# How do I use an object of a class as data of another class in a header file in c++?

Tags: c++

Say I have 3 files: `main.cpp`, `other.h` and `other.cpp`.
I want to create a class called other that includes a string and a vector as data.  If I write `other.h` like this:

```
    //other.h
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    class other
    {
    private:
        string str;
        vector<int> v;
    public:
        /*does not need to be included for this example,
        but would include constructors and functions.*/
    };
```

then my compiler will tell me string is not a type, even though I included it, and that I must specify the type of vector, even though I did.  How do I use a vector or string in my class without a compiler error?

Comment: It's `std::string`, every standard type is in the `std` namespace (Hint: that means you should do this for `vector` as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a `using namespace std;` or similar in your `main.cpp`. Such a statement would allow you to use unqualified names like `string` or `vector`. However, it is common practice (*particularly* in header files) to fully qualify names from the standard library - as `std::string` and `std::vector`.

See the question [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for further information.

Comment: @MrMan: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your question, please tick the check mark on the left to accept the answer.